# Program to run another through command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

I am not even sure if this question is answerable.
Basically in my game I am using the colorama features to make it look nice, but the colorama features only work when you access python in command prompt, so my question is how I can get python program to run another via command prompt, is this doable or not? I have tried installing win32 but that is in python 2 format and I am using 3.4 so I was getting syntax errors that I wasnt sure how to fix.

Comment: If you are on Windows, all Python scripts are executed in CMD Prompt when run - by default, so I don't see your problem. What you ask is possible, just, what OS are you on?

Comment: im on windows, but when i run the python.exe colorama doesnt work but when running using command line and typing py and python loads (obviously) and colorama works there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why is this happening, I mean, colorama not working without starting from prompt.

Perhaps something with environment variables PATH or something.

This is one suggestion, and I am not sure that it will work as we will not be changing the window program is running in, just invoking cmd.exe i.e. command prompt to start within it and start python and your script again.

But it is worth a try:

```
# Start of your program:
import sys, os

if "started_with_prompt" not in sys.argv:
    cmd = 'cmd /C "'+sys.executable+' '+" ".join(sys.argv)+' started_with_prompt"'
    os.system(cmd)
    sys.exit()
print "the rest of your program"
```

If this doesn't work, there are tricks that can be used through subprocess module to do the similar thing.
Also, you should look at cmd.exe's help to see whether you should use some other switch than /C to enable environment and/or registry extensions.

But, essentially, you should be able to get the same result by making a shortcut with the command like one in cmd variable, or a batch file that starts Python. Like this:

```
@echo off
cmd /C "C:\Python27\python.exe path_to_your_script.py"
```

I think both would work, but somehow that you wouldn't like this solution.

Well, I think that shortcut would need a full path to cmd.exe which is:
    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first suggestion, it works, not exactly sure what it is doing but it works which is the main thing. Thanks again.

Comment: 1. It checks how it is ran. 2. If just clicked it runs command prompt and Python within it, along with your script. Adds a switch to the call that tells script that it is ran with a prompt. 3. If it is ran with the switch, it assumes it is called by command prompt and continues with your program. So, your program starts twice. When clicked and then it cannot use Colorama, then calls itself within a command prompt, and then it can use it so it goes about its job. But this work around shouldn't be necessary. Something can be done to achieve the same result without this mess.

Comment: But I don't have Colorama so I don't know exactly what is happening here. As I wrote, the console your program starts with remains the same with first and the second call.  So it must be something in a way environment is set (most probably). Try printing os.environ before the if, and after it, to see eventual differences. If you see any significant changes, instead of my mess, try adding that to os.environ before importing Colorama. Perhaps it will be enough.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, its not much of a mess, its only 3 lines which were copy and pastable. i am not exactly sure why colorama doesnt work it python.exe though, someone i work with reckons it something to do with the way the text is outputted

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. Programs stdout and stderr are connected to the command prompt window, which does start with Python. And it should be instructable by Colorama regardless its parent process (process that started it). See cmd.exe, after you type in Python starts it and does no longer have control over what is outputed or not. Therefore it doesn't influence your program. If you don't see some gibberish outputed when you start it from Explorer then Colorama works as it should. What is happening here is that Python's window starts without terminal color supported, most probably.

Comment: That is why I told you to check environment. There should be a way to activate color mode within started terminal. How, I don't know right now. So do a little search. I told you it is a mess not because it is ugly, but because it is inelegant. Starting three processes at once to achieve what could be done in one. First Python, then it starts cmd which starts another Python. This should be solvable in more efficient way.

Comment: Hi @Dalen i have been using this code snippet since you gave it to me (its been great), but for some reason now, when i write new programs it doesnt work anymore but my old ones it does

Comment: and by that i mean it still closes the window if its opened with IDLE or any other IDE, its the colours that arent working anymore

Comment: If your old progs are working, but new aren't, then I have no idea what is going on. You did something somewhere that is causing the difference. Try running your program as administrator.